# onclick also redirects to "form action"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a little field for the password with a button next to it. If you click the button it shows your password and if you click it again it'll hide it. This all works fine, but right after it showed your password it'll do the action I've set for my form. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
<form action='bod.php' method='post'>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class='col-2'>
    <input type='text' name='Email' id='Email' placeholder='E-mail' class='input-effect form__input' value='$Email'>
     </td>
     <td class='col-2'>
    <input type='password' name='Wachtwoord' id='Wachtwoord' placeholder='Wachtwoord' class='input-effect form__input' value='$Wachtwoord'>
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type='image' src='img/eye.png' onClick='showPswd()' class='show'>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='col-2'>
    <input type='text' name='Bod' id='Bod' placeholder='Bod' class='input-effect form__input' onchange='controleerBod()'>
       </td>
       <td class='col-2'>
     <button type='submit' id='Bied'>Bied</button>
       </td>                            
      </tr>                     
   </table>
</form>



 // This is my JavaScript (it works)
// Show password
function showPswd() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Wachtwoord");
  if (x.type === "password") {
     x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

So if you click on the Image "eye.png" it'll show your password and if you click a second time it'll hide it.
Right now it shows your password and immediately reconnects to "bod.php"(the form action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **preventDefault()** function. And You also need to pass the **event** argument in your function

```
<input type='image' src='img/eye.png' onClick='showPswd(event)' class='show'>
```

This should be your JS code

```
function showPswd(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("Wachtwoord");
    if (x.type === "password") {
       x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use image, as image. Try this:

```
<img src='img/eye.png' onClick='showPswd()' class='show'>
```

Comment: I've tried this but I had some difficulties with it, but I've received a perfectly working answer above.